# Web service call using client certificate in SSIS script task resulting in SSL/TLS issue

Tags: c#, ssl, ssis

I've got an SSIS package in which I'm making a web service request and retrieving some data. The API provider requires that a client certificate be submitted alongside the request for security reasons.

I can get it to work perfectly fine if I run the package from the VS Shell (or even a VS console application) but when I deploy it and run the package via SQLAgent, firing it from SSMS, I get the following error:

> **System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'mywebservice.com/endpoint:6185'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5'1.b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory'1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func'2 endFunction, Action'1 endAction, Task'1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   ST_1ccd678422b8432a8ea14ce911c575f3.Myclass.<>c__DisplayClass39.<b__22>d__55.MoveNext()

I'm running the job as `NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$Instance` and the certificate has been placed in Local Machine, in the following stores: Personal, Trusted Root Certification Authorities, and Trusted People. This doesn't seem to be the issue though since I can get it to work with any of these when I debug via the VS shell/Data Tools.

I'd appreciate any help in advance, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing the following:

1. Set the job owner to `sa`.
2. Created a proxy account under SQL Server Agent --> Proxies --> SSIS Package Execution and set the Principal to my SQL login (domain) account. Also added the SQLAgent Reader, User, and Operator roles under the Principal.
3. Updated the SSIS job step by changing the SQL Server Agent Service Account to my new Proxy account

Hope this helps someone else.